# is it possible to build a Note-taking app like woodnotes using flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, input

I'm currently in school and using note-taking apps every day. Since I'm learning flutter for a few months now I was wondering, whether it's possible to build an app like good notes or OneNote using flutter. Does anyone have any kind of expertise in this field and if so knows good starting points?

Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why this wouldn't be possible. Check out packages like: https://pub.dev/packages/whiteboardkit to see how drawing is made possible. You can also look at OCR packages like: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_tesseract_ocr if you are interested in converting hand written notes into PDFs.

It goes without saying that it would take a great deal of work and you may need to create some custom packages for yourself if you want to include custom shapes or plugins but definitely possible!

Comment: Unfortunately, whiteboardkit is not supporting for a while and is not compatible with other packages, I searched a lot but I didn't find any good package who can support realtime onChaged for live whiteboard